# Connecting DAC to Mixer

Tags: dac

I am working on a project where I'm connecting two raspberry pis via RF.

I'm running into some difficulty when trying to figure out how to connect the components. I am trying to build my own RF system rather than just using a chip-IE, I want to run a digital signal from the pi through a DAC to an upmixer then to a filter and an antenna and broadcast to the second pi.

I know I want to use serial/SPI connections between DAC and pi but am getting stuck on how to connect the DAC to the mixer. Specifically, I am looking at the AD5684 DAC. To me it looks like it has 4 data outputs and that's where I'm getting confused.

Edit to add the data sheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1828690.pdf?_ga=1.162778300.1065408081.1469561785

Comment: Care to add a link to the datasheet for the AD5684?

Comment: It has 4 analog outputs.

Comment: It does have 4 analog outputs. I'm not sure how, if at all, those can connect to an upmixer.

Comment: If you are having trouble with the DAC then I foresee even greater trouble getting the RF side to work especially as you are "building my own".

Comment: Edit the datasheet link into your question.

Comment: Well, I came here looking for assistance. It may be that this project isn't viable, which is fine, but I need to exhaust all possible options before I'm comfortable with that outcome.

Comment: That is a Quad DAC - that means that it has four independent DACs.  If you only need one DAC, you just use one of the four outputs (or look for a single-channel DAC).

Comment: Does that mean that this particular DAC would be able to take the signal and send it out to 4 different locations? I thought that each independent DAC would process 1/4 of the input signal, but that's wrong?

Comment: @Asmodeuskraemer it's not that isn't viable - using DACs to control I and Q parts in a mixer is standerd enough (and the modern way) but you may be biting off more than you can chew especially as you don't appear to yet understand what a dac does.

Comment: The AD5684 is four independent DACs in one package.  The four DACs would normally handle four independent signals.

Comment: The basic premise of this question has zero viability. Wanting to design an RF data communication transmitter and receiver from scratch is admirable, but generating the carrier (or even modulation) through a DAC and "upmixing" the signal (whatever that means?) is completely impractical. It would appear to demonstrate that Asmodeuskraemer doesn't understand RF well enough to tackle such a complex project.  Even if Asmodeuskraemer did not USE one of the commercial solutions, they would be valuable instructional material as examples of efficient implementation of RF data links.

Comment: DAC = Digital to Analog converter. That chip accepts data as inputs and normally those inputs start with D0, D1 etc. There will be only one analog output

Comment: Up mixing is using a modulator to send the message on a carrier frequency that's much higher than the message frequency. WHY is it completely impractical? It seems like it'll be a lot of work but is certainly not out of the question. This is something I'm learning about and I don't appreciate your constant assertion that I don't understand RF enough to even ask this question. I'm asking because I want to understand, not to irritate you. Why did you come back to the thread after a month, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a digital signal out of the source (the RasPi), the best method is to simply modulate your RF carrier frequency with FSK (Frequency-Shift Keying). There is absolutely no place for conversion to analog or "upmixer". You don't seem to have a very good grasp of how digital signals are transmitted by RF, or what DACs are used for.

Comment: Hm, I thought I did but maybe you're right. Do you have any suggestions on where I can learn more? I've done plenty of googling on the subject but clearly I've not found the correct information.

Comment: There are plenty of sources for understanding how to make FSK transmitters and receivers.  But to be honest, your level of understanding will make this an impossible task. Even people with years of electronics experience would not tackle such a difficult project.  It is so incredibly easy and cheap to buy ready-made (and tested) transmitter/receivers for digital communication. You can even buy a matched transmitter and receiver for less than US$5  You need several more years of experience before you can tackle this kind of project successfully.  There are many FSK videos on YouTube,

Comment: Thank you for your honesty, I appreciate it. I know that I can buy ready-made parts. This is a project for a professor (who wants to build his own RF system) and while I'm a senior in EE, I definitely feel that I'm missing major chunks of knowledge. If you have any suggestions on books where I could start to fill in those holes that would be amazing.

Comment: To be clear, I understand that I can find tutorials on FSK and similar, I'm wondering how you knew that that would be a better option and I'd like to pick up that knowledge myself.

Comment: This is a rather advanced topic in RF circuit design.  Unless you have been studying RF circuits, you aren't ready for this kind of project.  You could make a simple FSK transmitter with a varicap diode. I saw many resources by Googling for "simple fsk modulation"

Comment: You can learn much by studying how commercial products are designed and constructed. Typically they use the best performing and most efficient methods to create commercially viable products.  Virtually ALL current RF transmission of digital signals uses FSK or some variation.  Study how things like WiFi and BlueTooth and cell phones are designed.

Comment: Well. Crap. But that's good to know. I've been struggling feeling stupid with this project for sometime but I don't feel so bad anymore. Always a silver lining. Thanks again. I'm waiting to hear back from my prof and I'll pass along the info.

Comment: I cannot move the discussion to chat, so sorry if things get long. I'll look into those things, they seems like good suggestions and things I'm interested in. Much appreciated.